# How much Gold would Zevlor have given me for killing the Goblins?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

After defeating a camp of goblins and returning to Emerald Cove, I was greeted by the Tiefling Zevlor. He thanked me for killing the Goblins so they could safely travel to Baldur's Gate. He said he'd gathered some gold to give as a reward, but I refused as it felt like the right thing to do. I am curious though...

How much gold would Zevlor have given me if I'd accepted his reward?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zevlor will give you the *Patched-Together Sack*, a container which is also useful for sorting items in your inventory.

This sack contains **63 gold**, a gemstone, a Potion of Healing, and a weapon:

[image]

I take it these items are all somewhat randomized every time the container is opened.

What's much more interesting, however, is that **it contains** [**Wapira's Crown**](https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Wapira%27s_Crown), an organic looking uncommon helmet decorated with antlers, which will heal the wielder for 1d6 whenever they heal someone else. It also can't be obtained in any other way (apart from mods, I presume):

[image: In-game item description of Wapira's Crown]

On my current playthrough it was a welcome (and quite pretty) addition to Shadowheart's gear.